# In Which format the date is given?

Tags: date, datetime, dataset, uci

I have downloaded a dataset called **Real estate valuation data set** from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Real+estate+valuation+data+set?source=post_page . But I am not able to understand in which format the transaction date is given. They have given some examples like **2013.250=2013 March, 2013.500=2013 June**, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem and I figured that the months were represented as a fraction of a year. So, for instance, June is the 6th month of the year, hence it is 6/12 = 0.5; that's why we had June 2013 as 2013.500, etc.